# Why is fork + exec used to create new processes in an OS?

Tags: process, operating-system, fork

Every operating system uses the same model to create new processes. The parent forks itself and then exec's the child. But why is this model so overwhelmingly popular?

In a typical fork+exec model the OS has to create a copy of the entire process space (granted some optimizations are done with copy-on-write etc.) and then when the exec is done the new program's code and data/stack need to be set up along with the rest of the meta data.

Now if I can call into the OS directly and say there is a system call exec_new() then it can do the same thing like above without the need for two syscalls. The owner will still be the same UID. Why is this not done? What does the fork+exec model give us?

Answer (score 0):

> Every operating system uses the same model to create new processes. The parent forks itself and then exec's the child.

This is not correct. That is the eunuchs model. I don't know of any other operating system that does things that way. Other systems include library functions to emulate eunuchs but that tends not to be the underlying mechanism.

E.g. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx

http://h41379.www4.hpe.com/doc/83final/4527/4527pro_025.html

A common model in large scale operating systems is that the command interpreter exists in a protected area of the process. One runs multiple programs in the same process. This is in contrast to the eunuchs shell that is simply a program that kicks off other programs using the mechanism you describe.